# Why aren't 'exons' named 'introns'?

Tags: molecular-biology, homework, transcription, history, introns

Why are introns called 'introns' when they are the actual ones who are getting spliced out from the pre-mRNA. Shouldn't exons be named introns as they are the ones that are 'in' and are not 'exiting'? On what criteria were they named like this?

Comment: It confuses me too. Shrug.

Comment: **In**trons stay **in**side the nucleus, **ex**ons **ex**it the nucleus.

Comment: It’s not actually true that introns always stay inside the nucleus. There is a lot of research discussing the role of extranuclear introns playing a role in translation regulation.

Comment: I'm amazed how many votes this has got. Shows that there is a general confusion among those new to the topic. If I were still teaching this, I'd make an extra effort to clarify the origin of the expression. I withdraw my close vote.

Comment: @David It was in the "Hot Questions" list, which makes it visible to everyone across Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The terms *intron* and *exon* were coined by [Walter Gilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Gilbert#cite_note-20) in a renowned 'News and Views' article, [Why Genes in Pieces](http://www.readcube.com/articles/10.1038/271501a0), published in the journal *Nature* in 1978.

Introns are the *intragenic* regions and exons are the regions which are *expressed*.

This is the relevant passage in full:

> The notion of the cistron, the genetic unit of function that one thought corresponded to a polypeptide chain, now must be replaced by that of a transcription unit containing regions which will be lost from the mature messenger - which I suggest we call introns (for intragenic regions) - alternating with regions which will be expressed - exons. The gene is a mosaic: expressed sequences held in a matrix of silent DNA, an intronic matrix.

Comment: Yeah I got the link of the article from Nature.com . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, as this question seems to be about helping the X- or M- generations get to grips with baby boomer terminology, let me explain how I remember what introns are.

Before Gilbert coined the term (as @xusr explains) original reports of the research that established the mosaic nature of eukaryotic genes refered to

> **in**-*tervening sequences*.

For example, there was a paper from [Phil Leder’s lab in 1978](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC411329/pdf/pnas00014-0197.pdf) entitled

> **Intervening** sequence of DNA identified in the structural portion of amouse β-globin gene

So *intron* was really related to *intervening* in its origin, and knowning this it is easy to remember which is which — introns and exons.